# Required gives an error after the input tag is filled - Html

Tags: html, required

I put a requirement in the input tag and it works fine the first time and when the user leaves the input tag empty it gives an error but the next time even if that tag is filled the page still gives an error. until the page is refreshed.
this is my code

```
`<form action="/Comments/Create" method="post" dir="rtl">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="tst-rating" style="font-size:28px;">
<a href=""><img id="star5" src="~/Content/images/star1.png" width="40" height="40" style="margin-left:-7px;" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="star4" src="~/Content/images/star1.png" width="40" height="40" style="margin-left:-7px;" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="star3" src="~/Content/images/star1.png" width="40" height="40" style="margin-left:-7px;" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="star2" src="~/Content/images/star1.png" width="40" height="40" style="margin-left:-7px;" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="star1" src="~/Content/images/star1.png" width="40" height="40" /></a>
                            </div>
<input type="text" name="FullName" class="form-control" placeholder="نام" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('لطفا نام خود را وارد کنید')">

<input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="ایمیل (اختیاری)">

<textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="نظر خود را بنویسید" name="CommentText" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('لطفا نظر خود را بنویسید')"></textarea>

<input type="submit" class="submit-btn form-control" id="form-submit" value="ارسال" />

</form>`
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. Neither does the `<input>` tag and you are inconsistent in its usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be caused duo to the "required" atribute expecting a boolean value. Try changing `required=""` to only `required`.

Comment: Thank you.. the problem was from oninvalid, the problem was solved by deleting oninvalid.. but now I don't know how to show the desired text for the error without oninvalid

Comment: The oninvalid event is not supported in Safari.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to display the desired message?